# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/types/ObjectId

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, extentreports

```
@Test
public void loginTest() {

    System.out.println("Login to amazon");

    ExtentHtmlReporter reporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("./Reports/result.html");

    ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();

    extent.attachReporter(reporter);

    ExtentTest logger = extent.createTest("loginTest");

    logger.log(Status.INFO, "login to amazon");

    extent.flush();

}
```

i have tried  to generate extentreport using testNG framework but getting this error...someone help me on this please

Logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.types.ObjectId
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please add the logs error messages you are getting.

Comment: there may be some problem with dependency.

Comment: You need to check that dependency to [`org.mongodb/bson`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/bson) is resolved in your project

Comment: try using the latest version of extent report from mvnrepository. Also check if all the dependencies are resolved in your project.